# Encoding secret keys and passwords in PHP files

Tags: php, encoding

I have a website that uses mysql database, as well as amazon S3. Currently, I have all the passwords and info for the database and for the S3, just written down in php files.

I was thinking, since I am not the only developer working on the project, it would be great to encode sensitive data somehow, so it is hidden in files, and hidden for anyone other accessing the files through ftp or cpanel.

I have no idea where to start looking for the answer to this. Is it even possible? There may be some kind of third party, that can encode everything, but I just don't know yet.

Please if anyone has some ideas, or has any experience with this kinda stuff, share your knowledge with me and anyone having the same issue.

Comment: Normally passwords aren't stored anywhere, the only person who knows the password is the user. This is made possible with hashes. See: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php Regrettably you cannot do this with database passwords. The only way to protect this type of sensitive data is to control and restrict access.

Comment: I suggest you create a salt unique to each user and then hash the password with the salt the same way each time and then compare the hash to the hash in the database - that way, only the user knows the password.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. However, I know how to do it when users type the password, it should be encrypted in the database. But, problem is with my database username, password and Amazon S3 secret keys and credentials. They just stay there in a file, like $pass = "password" and if anyone opens the file from ftp or cpanel, they can see the passwords and other details. I was thinking to prevent that somehow, but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For passwords I recommend these 2 php functions
password_hash() and password_verify().

Comment: It is a good solution, but for passwords in the database. However, I need to do something with passwords in the files, for example - database info and amazon S3 secret keys. Now, I just store them like $pass = "password" then use mysqli_connect to connect etc etc